# irregular output at android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am developing an android app for my friend. 
I want to make a good looking for a list. 
It Works fine at the terminal but not on the app.

How can I make it as at the terminal?

[app view](https://ufukglr.com/apk/1.png)
[terminal view](https://ufukglr.com/apk/2.png)
java code:

```
c = c.format("%3s", c);
d = d.format("%3s", d);
e = e.format("%2s", e);
arrayList.add(a+" | "+b+" | "+c+" | "+d+" | "+e+"/"+f);
```

xml code

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/genel_liste"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"/>
```

Comment: You should probably parse the text and put each value in its own element with a title or description. Just listing the same text but with more vertical spacing isn't really going to look any better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a monospaced font. As long as your device is using a relatively modern version of Android (API 17, iirc), you can set this directly on your `<TextView>` tag to do so:

```
android:fontFamily="monospace"
```